# Is this solution to a claculus of variations problem correct?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

We have the functional $I(x)=\int^3_2 y^2(1-y')^2dx$ and we want to find an extremal that satisfies some boundary conditions.

I found the Euler equation (I think):

\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} &= -2y^2(1 - y') \implies  \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\bigg) = -4yy'(1-y') +2y^2y'' \\
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} &= 2y(1-y')^2
\end{align*}

We get the equation $2y(1-y')^2 = -4yy'(1-y') +2y^2y''$:

\begin{align*}
 &2(1-y')^2 = -4y'(1-y') +2yy''\\
 \iff& 2(1-2y' + y'^2) = -4y'(1-y') +2yy''\\
 \iff& 2-4y' + 2y'^2 = -4y' +4y'^2 +2yy''\\
 \iff& 1 - y'^2 = yy''\\
\end{align*}

I don;t know how to solve that, so by inspection I am really tempted to say it must be a trig function because if the equation was $-yy'' = 1-y'^2$ $\cos$ would totally be a solution.

Comment: $$yy'' = 1 - y'^{2} \implies yy'' + y'^{2} = 1 \implies (yy')' = 1 \implies \frac{1}{2} (y^{2})'' = 1$$

Comment: I see, that makes sense, but how do you solve that last part? I am trying U substitution but since y is a funciton of x I am getting tangled.

Comment: You also get that $H=y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-F$ is a constant along solutions. This might give the first integration a little simpler. Further, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0$ at the interval boundaries, that is either $y=0$ or $y'=1$ there. You might have to check which combination gives the lowest value of the functional.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2} (y^{2})'' = 1 \implies \frac{1}{2} (y^{2})' = x + C_{1} \implies \frac{1}{2} y^{2} = \frac{x^{2}}{2} + C_{1} x + C_{2}$$